# Nested if with vlookup and hyperlinks to folder - Excel

Tags: excel

I am able to use vlookup to get a folder address from a table and ensure it appears as a hyperlink. However, I am unable to put this into a nested if so that I can look through multiple tables.

The following formula only works for the first if statement.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(G11,database!$D$3:$F$1000,2,FALSE) <> 0, HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(G11,database!$D$3:$F$1000,2,FALSE),""),
IF(VLOOKUP(G11,database!$H$3:$I$1000,2,FALSE) <> 0, HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(G11,database!$H$3:$I$1000,2,FALSE),"")))
```

Comment: You are using same formula twice. What is your end goal?

Comment: *The following formula only works for the first if statement.* What does that mean?

Comment: The database sheet contains two tables:
table 1: ($D$3:$F$1000)
| report | report link |

table 2: $H$3:$I$1000
|template | template link |

Comment: "following formula only works for the first if statement", means that the first if statement is able to correctly get the value, but the second is not (the else if does not resolve to a solution).

Comment: I think the issue was about not handling error correctly:

=IFERROR(HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(G5,database!$D$3:$F$1000,2,FALSE),""),HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(G5,database!$H$3:$I$1000,2,FALSE),""))

going to see whether this works with more data tables...

Answer (score 0):

Handle errors better:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(G5,database!$D$3:$F$1000,2,FALSE),""),HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(G5,database!$H$3:$I$1000,2,FALSE),""))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).